# How do I add an HTML element into a div using jQuery while passing variables as content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a list like so:

```
<ul id="my-list">
    <li class="list-item" data-role="collapsible">List Item</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-role="collapsible">List Item</li>
    <li class="list-item" data-role="collapsible">List Item</li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to add another `li` element with the class `list-item` and maybe the data-role `collapsible` at the end of the list. But, I want to pass the contents of a variable to the inside of the new `li` tag. Say the variable is `var myVariable = "Contents of Variable";` Is there a way to do this using jQuery and/or JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myVariable = "Contents of Variable";
$("#my-list").append("<li class='list-item' data-role='collapsible'>" + myVariable + "</li>");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could clone one of the existing tags:

```
$('#my-list li').first().clone().text(myVariable).appendTo('#my-list');
```

And with plain JavaScript:

```
var list = document.getElementById('my-list');
var elem = list.firstChild.cloneNode();
elem.textContent = myVariable;
list.appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/MFBwt/1/)** ?

```
var myVariable = "Contents of Variable";

x(myVariable);

function x(obj) {
    $('#my-list').append('<li class="list-item" data-role="collapsible">' + obj + '</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
function create(content){
    $('<li />', {
        class: 'list-item',
        'data-role': 'collapsible'
    }).html(content).appendTo('#my-list')
}

create('my content')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ndkcc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`$('#my-list').append('<li class="list-item" data-role="collapsible">' + myVariable + '</li>');`